# Objective-c conditionally add to NSDictionary using BOOL

Tags: objective-c, boolean, nsdictionary

I'm trying to add objects (Hospitals) into an NSDictionary when the 'pack ID' for the Hospital matches the current one and it is marked as selected.

The selected attribute is a BOOL so I have tried each of the following with no success in the if statement:

- `hospital.selected == TRUE`
- `hospital.selected == YES`
- `hospital.selected == 1`

All of these produce the same results, if selected is equal to 1 or 0 it gets added. they only filter out the nil results.

```
    NSString * NAME      = @"name";
    NSString * PHONE   = @"phone";
    NSString * POSTCODE = @"postcode";

    NSMutableArray * mArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSDictionary * dict;

    for(ecossHospitalObject *hospital in results){

     @try{
        NSLog(@"self pack id: %i, hospital pack id: %@", self.fullDataObject.dataPack.pack_id, hospital.dataObject.dataPack.pack_id);
        NSLog(@"hospital.selected %hhd", hospital.selected);
        if(self.fullDataObject.dataPack.pack_id == [hospital.dataObject.dataPack.pack_id integerValue] && hospital.selected == 1){

                dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        hospital.name, NAME,
                        hospital.telephone, PHONE,
                        hospital.postCode, POSTCODE,
                        nil];

                [mArray addObject:dict];
        }

     }@catch(NSException *e){
        NSLog(@"NSException %@", e);
     }

    }
```

Where `hospital.selected` is nil I get 0 in the log where it is 0 or 1 I get random numbers (currently 48 and 96 respectively).

The Hospital objects are created using the following method:

```
+(NSMutableArray*) parseJsonHospitalArray : (NSMutableArray *) jsonArray
{


NSMutableArray *parsedData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


for (id object in jsonArray) {
    ecossHospitalObject *hospitalData = [[ecossHospitalObject alloc] init];

    hospitalData.address = [object objectForKey:@"address"];
    hospitalData.code1 = [object objectForKey:@"code1"];
    hospitalData.code2 = [object objectForKey:@"code2"];
    hospitalData.distance = [self getIntForString:[object objectForKey:@"distance"]];
    hospitalData.hasAE = [[object objectForKey:@"has_a_and_e"] boolValue];
    hospitalData.ID = [self getIntForString:[object objectForKey:@"id"]];
    hospitalData.latitude = [object objectForKey:@"latitude"];
    hospitalData.longitude = [object objectForKey:@"longitude"];
    hospitalData.name = [object objectForKey:@"name"];
    hospitalData.postCode = [object objectForKey:@"postcode"];
    hospitalData.selected = [[object objectForKey:@"selected"] boolValue];
    hospitalData.telephone = [object objectForKey:@"telephone"];
    hospitalData.website = [object objectForKey:@"website"];


    [parsedData addObject: hospitalData];
}

return parsedData;


 }
```

Here is the data printed out:

```
data: ({
       address = nil;
       code1 = nil;
       code2 = nil;
       dataObject = "0x1587d330 <x-coredata://69494056-6039-4679-9C66-7394E9795700/DataObject/p10>";
       distance = 0;
       "hasA_E" = nil;
       hospitalDirectionsArray = nil;
       hospitalImageLocation = nil;
       iD = 0;
       latitude = nil;
       longitude = nil;
       name = "John Radcliffe Hospital - A & E";
       postCode = "OX3 9DU";
       selected = nil;
       telephone = "01865 741166";
       website = nil;
   },
   {
       address = "Headley Way, Headington, Oxford, Oxfordshire";
       code1 = RTH08;
       code2 = nil;
       dataObject = "0x17741940 <x-coredata://69494056-6039-4679-9C66-7394E9795700/DataObject/p10>";
       distance = 14;
       "hasA_E" = 1;
       hospitalDirectionsArray = nil;
       hospitalImageLocation = nil;
       iD = 645;
       latitude = "51.7638761156";
       longitude = "-1.2198152232602";
       name = "John Radcliffe Hospital - A & E";
       postCode = "OX3 9DU";
       selected = 1;
       telephone = "01865 741166";
       website = nil;
},
{
      address = "Oxford Rd, Banbury, Oxfordshire";
      code1 = RTH05;
      code2 = nil;
      dataObject = "0x17741940 <x-coredata://69494056-6039-4679-9C66-7394E9795700/DataObject/p10>";
      distance = 19;
      "hasA_E" = 1;
      hospitalDirectionsArray = nil;
      hospitalImageLocation = nil;
      iD = 623;
      latitude = "52.053503457165";
      longitude = "-1.3366590559482";
      name = "Horton General Hospital - A & E";
      postCode = "OX16 9AL";
      selected = 0;
      telephone = "01295 275500";
      website = nil;
},
{
      address = "Standing Way, Eaglestone, Milton Keynes, Buckinghamshire";
      code1 = RD816;
      code2 = nil;
      dataObject = "0x17741940 <x-coredata://69494056-6039-4679-9C66-7394E9795700/DataObject/p10>";
      distance = 41;
      "hasA_E" = 1;
      hospitalDirectionsArray = nil;
      hospitalImageLocation = nil;
      iD = 789;
      latitude = "52.026356870309";
      longitude = "-0.73577247002525";
      name = "Milton Keynes Hospital - A & E";
      postCode = "MK6 5LD";
      selected = 0;
      telephone = "01908 660033";
      website = nil;
  },
  {
      address = "Mandeville Road, Aylesbury, Buckinghamshire";
      code1 = RXQ02;
      code2 = nil;
      dataObject = "0x17741940 <x-coredata://69494056-6039-4679-9C66-7394E9795700/DataObject/p10>";
      distance = 34;
      "hasA_E" = 1;
      hospitalDirectionsArray = nil;
      hospitalImageLocation = nil;
      iD = 1333;
      latitude = "51.800759137118";
      longitude = "-0.80484777392717";
      name = "Stoke Mandeville Hospital - A & E";
      postCode = "HP21 8AL";
      selected = 0;
      telephone = "01296 315000";
      website = nil;
  }
)
```

Comment: None of the code you posted has `hospital.selected`.

Comment: If `selected` can be nil, then it's an object rather than a boolean.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks, edited.

Comment: @NimitParekh isEqual: gives 'Bad receiver type 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char')

Comment: Did you try logging the value of your `hospital.selected` value? What is its type? Spend a little quality time with the debugger.

Comment: @rmaddy I have logged the value of `hospital.selected` and it gives some seemingly random number

Comment: Update your question with relevant code for populating that value.

Comment: No. Post the code where you actually put a value into the `selected` property.

Comment: @rmaddy OH! lol, my bad...2 seconds

Comment: @rmaddy Think that's what you're after

Comment: Reduce your question to only include the code neccessary for readers to understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(self.fullDataObject.dataPack.pack_id == [hospital.dataObject.dataPack.pack_id integerValue] 
     && hospital.selected == 1){
```

Stop right there. Never never never *never* use a comparison test *as* a conditional. Your code says, in effect:

```
if (hospital.selected == 1)
```

That is *wrong*. So is `if (hospital.selected == YES)` and `if (hospital.selected == TRUE)`. They are *all* wrong. They are doomed to failure and random behavior.

If you've set this up correctly, `hospital.selected` *is* a boolean. It *is* a condition. So you just say:

```
if (hospital.selected)
```

That is the only way to get the right answer consistently.

**EDIT** If `hospital.selected` is an NSNumber wrapping a Bool, then to use it as a conditional, use `boolValue` — that is, say

```
if (hospital.selected.boolValue)
```

This will fail gracefully if the NSNumber is `nil`, and will work correctly otherwise. But do *not* assume that it can be only 0 and 1; that is a major mistake.

Comment: Thanks for this answer but the problem is that `hospital.selected` can be nil 0 or 1 and I only need access to it when it equals 1. This gives me 0 and 1.

Comment: If it can be nil, then I presume it is an NSNumber wrapping a Bool in that case. So use `boolValue` and do what I said to do, thus: `if (hospital.selected.boolValue)`. Do _not_ assume that it can be only 0 and 1. Do _not_ compare against 0 or 1. That is the mistake I am warning you against.

Answer (score 0):

```
hospitalData.selected = [[object objectForKey:@"selected"]boolValue];
```

you can directly convert 0 And 1 in to bool yes or no

and if u want to add Bool value Yes or No to server in 1 or 0

You can add it like

```
selected : @(hospitalData.selected)
```